# Replace each item in the list that is the same, with the same item

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I'm trying to right code that iterates over each item in a list to replace all matching items with the same thing. At the moment, only the first instance is replaced. It is for a hangman style game. Here is my code:

```
    if guess in self.word:
        print(f"Good guess! {guess} is in the word.")
        guessed = True
            for g in self.word:
                if g == guess:
                    guess_index = self.word.find(guess)
                    self.word_guessed[guess_index] = guess
            self.num_letters -= 1
            print(f"Your progress so far: {self.word_guessed}.")

    else:
        self.num_lives -= 1
        print(f"Sorry. {guess} is not in the word. Try again.")
        print(f"You have {self.num_lives} lives left.")
        print(f"Your progress so far: {self.word_guessed}.")
```

Any ideas how I can makes sure each instance is replaced. I think I need some form of while loop but not sure what the conditions should be.

I have tried different while loops but can't find one to work. If the word being guessed is apple, I end up with [a,p,_,l,e]

Answer (score 1):

To replace all instances of the guessed letter in the word, you don't need a while loop. You can continue using a for loop, but you need to adjust how you're updating the word_guessed list.

Currently, you're finding the index of the first occurrence of the guessed letter and replacing it, but you need to find all occurrences and replace them.
Try this :

```
class HangmanGame:
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.word_guessed = ['_' for _ in word]
        self.num_letters = len(word)
        self.num_lives = 6

    def guess_letter(self, guess):
        if guess in self.word:
            print(f"Good guess! {guess} is in the word.")
            guessed = True
            for i in range(len(self.word)):
                if self.word[i] == guess:
                    self.word_guessed[i] = guess
            self.num_letters -= 1
            print(f"Your progress so far: {' '.join(self.word_guessed)}.")

        else:
            self.num_lives -= 1
            print(f"Sorry. {guess} is not in the word. Try again.")
            print(f"You have {self.num_lives} lives left.")
            print(f"Your progress so far: {' '.join(self.word_guessed)}.")


# Example usage:
game = HangmanGame("hangman")
game.guess_letter("a")
```

Output:

```
Good guess! a is in the word.
Your progress so far: _ a _ _ _ a _.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need class for this guess game implementation

```
def guess_me(secret='Replace each item in the list', moves=5):
    guess  = ''.join(i if i.isspace() else '_' for i in secret)
    print(guess)
    while moves > 0:
        x = input(f'moves {moves} enter letter ')
        if x in secret:
            guess = ''.join(i if i==x else guess[n] for n,i in enumerate(secret))
            print(guess)
        else:
            moves -= 1
            print('nope')
        if guess == secret: return True
    return False
```